# Problem with transform in GRIB using GDAL

Tags: raster, gdal, coordinate-system

I'm getting some strange numbers out of a GRIB file (from a different source than others we process) and am not experienced enough with GRIB and GDAL to quite understand what is going on.

If I call GetProjectionRef I receive this:

```
GEOGCS["Coordinate System imported from GRIB file",DATUM["unknown",SPHEROID["Sphere",6367470,0]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]]
```

That would suggest to me that I should we working in lat/lon degrees. However, when I call GetGeoTransform I receive

```
[0] -2047.4836475
[1] -1E-06
[2] 0
[3] 74.9999995
[4] 0
[5] 1E-06
```

This seems inconsistent to me, particularly given that I know the top left corner of the raster should be at 75N 100W. The longitude of the transform appears to be correct, but all the rest are a mystery to me.

I also queried it with a different library (grib.api) and it also has trouble computing coordinates for the data, and lists the x and y direction stepsizes as "MISSING". However, if I open the GRIB file in the Panoply viewer, it seems to have no problems.

Am I overlooking something obvious (almost certainly!) or is the file ill-formed?